# Can create a URL File in OneDrive Web UI but NOT correctly through Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I can easily create a URL File through the O365 OneDrive web UI.  Right click > New > Link.  Enter the URL and save. The new item appears in the UI and when clicked, it will take you directly to the new URL, let's say it's www.google.com.

I'm attempting to duplicate this with the Graph API.

```
GET /me/drive/items/{folderId}/children
with: 
{ name:'www.google.com.url',
  file:{}
}
```

It creates what appears to be a link in the OneDrive UI but when clicked, it will not take you to the URL, it attempts to download a file.  I've tried creating it with and without the .url suffix.  The API looks pretty limited and there aren't many options to pass.  I've also tried the beta API, same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Links are actually a file with a special syntax similar to an INI file. From the sample you included here, it looks like you're creating an empty (0 byte) file named "www.google.com.url". Since the empty file doesn't match the format expected for a .URL file, OneDrive doesn't know what to do with it and just downloads the file.

To create a link programmatically, you would need to make a request like this:

```
PUT https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children/ShortcutToBing.url/content
Content-Type: text/plain

[InternetShortcut]
URL=https://www.bing.com
```

This will create a file named ShortcutToBing.url, and fill the contents of the file with the text below the request, which is the contents of a .URL file, pointing to www.bing.com.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, it worked!  I really like the Graph API and it works well but it would good if little things like this were documented somewhere.  Maybe they are but it's not easy to find.  Anyway, thanks again!!

Comment: In this case, the API doesn't have any special concept around "links" like SharePoint does. The format of .URL files was defined long ago and SharePoint just added some special behavior around how they work. Since the file format is well defined you can upload a file that matches the format (which is what the API cal I provided is doing). It does seem interesting to add richer support around a concept of "links" though to enable this more directly.